# Limit on number of Firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase

I used to add many projects under a Firebase account but this time when I wanted to create a project under Firebase console then it says that **You are three projects away**. I already had two projects under the console. Is the limit now reduced to 5 apps per account?

Answer (score 2):

I found this info on the firebase faq site

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/

"How many Firebase apps can I have in a project?

A project is a container for apps across iOS, Android and web. While there is no restriction on number of apps within a project, adding an app can create one or more underlying OAuth 2.0 client IDs. There is a limit of around 30 client IDs that can be created within a single project.

You should ensure that all apps within a project are platform variants of the same application from an end user perspective. For example, if you develop a white label application, each independently labelled app should have its own Firebase project."

Answer (score 1):

In [this link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231), you can find out more about the limitations of Google Project (API Console Project, Google Cloud Project, and Firebase Project). And you will also be able to request quota upgrades when you reach the limit.

Here's an extract:

> "If you attempt to exceed your project limit, the console will prompt you to fill out a request form. This happens when you try to create a project but you have already reached your quota. The form will require you to specify the number of additional projects you need, along with their corresponding email accounts, billing accounts, and intended uses."

Answer (score 0):

The limit on the number of projects is not a fixed number. It varies based on your account's standing.

Keep in mind that both Google Cloud projects and Firebase projects count towards the same total number of projects, so be sure to also check [console.cloud.google.com](http://console.cloud.google.com/) for projects.